Override font of a template in a show rule
I have this MWE of a template (imported via typst.app) and my document (below). Is it possible to change the font of the #show call in this example without touching the original template?
// This is the imported part of the template
#let template(
  title: [The Title],
  body
) =  {
  set document(title: title)
  // Set text fonts and sizes
  set text(font: "Inter", size: 11pt)
  page(text(2em)[*#title*])
  body
}

and this is my document.
// This is my document
#show: template.with(
  title: [This is the Title]
)

= Headline
#lorem(50)

I'm still in the process of trying to figure out the syntax. Help much appreciated.

I've done additional research and, thanks to a hint on the Typst Discord, found this one-line solution:
// This must be set *before* the #show call of the template
#show page: set text(font: "Comic Neue")

Possible exceptions: As far as I understand it, the specificity/strictness of #show page: is higher than of a general set text (as used in the template in my case). So this might fail if the template in question defines the font (or other values) for certain elements with higher strictness.
In these cases, something even more strict like #show outline: set text(font: "Comic Neue") or #show bibliography: set text(font: "Comic Neue") may be necessary. But the line above was the closest I got to a global font change.

The title parameter accepts the content type value, so you can pass text(font: "xxx")[This is the title] to change the font of the title:
#show: template.with(
  title: text(font: "xxx")[This is the title]
)

And for the body part, you can use #set text(font: "xxx") after the show rule to change the font.

Thanks! Okay, but there is no equivalent to something like !important in CSS or \renewcommand[…] in LaTeX for a global font setting that you're aware of, right? The template in question, namely 'nifty-ntnu-thesis', also includes an abstract, TOC, etc., that would need to be adapted. For the abstract and anything that accepts the content type value, the suggested approach works. However, for the TOC and bibliography, I suppose it does not (which, of course, wasn't part of my MWE).

Addendum: I tried approaches like #let template() = { set text(font: "xxx", size: 11pt) } but (as to be expected) that empties the whole template function. So I couldn't find a way to just redefine the set text inside.
